# Billingcity picklist same as like country and state

Tags: visualforce

I am using Below code to get the Country and State picklist on Account.

```
 <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Billingcountrycode}" ></apex:inputfield>
 <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Billingstatecode}" </apex:inputfield>
```

is it possible to use BillingCity based on selected Billingstatecode.
I have tried with Billingcitycode but its is not working.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you mean display Billing City, then use BillingCity, if you mean show a lot of cities based on the state code, you will have to roll your own as SF does not have a list of all cities by state.

Answer (score 2):

There is no out-of-the-box picklist for City the way there is one for State/Country. You must roll your own solution if you need to have cities be automatically determined by the country/postal combination.